# Can't Get ASP.NET MVC Form To Post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having problems getting my form to Post to my Save method in a controller. I am new to MVC, and have followed several examples to try to get this to work. Here is my html markup:

```
    <form action="Edit/Save" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Personal Information</legend>

            <table class="editGrid">
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="txtFirstName">First Name:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="txtFirstName" value="<%=user.FirstName %>" name="FirstName" /></td>                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="txtLastName">Last Name:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="txtLastName" value="<%=user.LastName %>" name="LastName" /></td>                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="txtNtLogin">NT Login:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="txtNtLogin" value="<%=user.NtLogin %>" name="NtLogin" /></td>                   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="txtHireDate">Hire Date:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="txtHireDate" value="<%=string.Format("{0:d}",user.HireDate) %>" name="HireDate" /></td>               
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Job Information</legend>

            <table class="editGrid">
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="CostCenters">Cost Center:</label></td>
                    <td><%=Html.DropDownList("CostCenters")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="Managers">Manager:</label></td>
                    <td><%=Html.DropDownList("Managers")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="Responsibilities">Responsibility:</label></td>
                    <td><%=Html.DropDownList("Responsibilities")%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="Departments">Department:</label></td>
                    <td><%=Html.DropDownList("Departments")%></td>                        
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="Active">Active:</label></td>
                    <td><%=Html.CheckBox("Active",user.Active) %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="txtHireDate">Hire Date:</label></td>
                    <td><%=Html.TextBox("txtHireDate",string.Format("{0:d}",user.HireDate)) %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="txtReleaseDate">Release Date:</label></td>
                    <td><%=Html.TextBox("txtReleaseDate",string.Format("{0:d}",user.ReleaseDate)) %></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />    
</form>
```

This form routes to a Save method in my EditController. Here is the code for my EditController's Save method:

```
    public class EditController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Save()
        {
//Save code goes here
          }
```

I have tried using the html form tag, and also the Html helper code:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Edit"))
```

Here is the entry from my RegisterRoutes method in the Global.asax file:

```
    routes.MapRoute("EditSave", "{controller}/Save",
                    new { controller = "Edit", action = "Save" });
```

No matter what I do, the submit button does not trigger the Save method. Yet, if I manually key in the Url, The code breaks right into the Save method.

Edit:
Per Craig Stuntz's comment, I checked the source of the page. The page actually contains 2 forms, although only 1 is coded on the page by myself: Here is the HTML that appears prior to my form tag:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="44" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNjM3OTAyNTUzZGQrHhVn9+t78aHxN0vHvKUJ8DQWlQ==" />
</div>

                <div id="nav">
                    <span id="navLinks">
                        <a href="#">Placeholder Link</a>
                    </span>
                    <span id="userName">
                        <span id="ctl00_lblUserName" class="UserName">Welcome, Test User</span>
                    </span> 
                </div> 

                <div id="Content">


    <div id="formContainer">

            <form action="Edit/Save" method="post">
```

I didn't think MVC generated viewstate or additional form tags. I am pulling data and populating it into this form using another method from the same controller. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What form-action URL is in the rendered HTML (in the browser)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got the answer. And thanks Craig for having me look at the HTML again! My master page had generated a form tag in it without my knowing it, so I essentially had nested forms on the same page. After I removed the form from the Master Page, everything worked perfectly.